# ¿Como ingresar dos valores a un mismo indice de array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-bidimensional

Estoy trabjando con React Leaflet y necesito pasar un valor para dibujar una polilinea, este es el valor que segun la documentación necesito pasar.

```
const polyline = [
  [51.505, -0.09],
  [51.51, -0.1],
  [51.51, -100.12],
]
```

Hasta el momento esta es mi función para acomodar los datos

```
    const drawLine = () => {
        for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
            track.push([
            points[i].latitude,
            points[i].longitude
            ]);
        }
        console.log(track);
    }
```

Pero la salida, no es exactamente como la esperaba, ya que me está entregando lo siguiente.

```
[0 … 9999]
[0 … 99]
0: Array(2)
0: [19.574815]
1: [-96.90457333333333]
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Así que mi pregunta es la siguiente. ¿Como puedo hacer para armar un arreglo identico al que me pide la [documentación](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-vector-layers/)?

Comment: Hace falta un poco más de información. ¿cómo inicializas `track`? ¿qué contiene `points`? Por favor, considera agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería de gran ayuda saber la forma que tiene tu variable points, pero en base a tu bucle `for` supongo que tiene esta forma:

```
const points = [{ latitude: 51.505, longitude: -0.09}, { latitude: 51.51, longitude: -0.1}, {latitude: 51.51, longitude: -100.12}]
```

En base a eso para poder formar la salida que tu quieres, al menos para mi, me parecio mas rapido, y con pocas lineas de codigo hacer de esta menera:

```
const track = points.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]))
```

con map se recorre cada uno de los objetos que contiene el arreglo de objetos points.
`Object.keys(obj)` regresa un arreglo con los keys del objeto que se esta iterando con `.map`

```
Array [ "latitude", "longitude" ]
```

Entonces, en ese arreglo interno se usa otra vez `.map` para iterar los dos keys que se muestra en el ejemplo de arriba. Al hacer esto `obj[key]`, se obtiene el valor del objeto, seria algo como `objeto['longitude]` o  `objeto['latitude']` y ambos valores se regresan como un arreglo `[ 51.505, -0.09]` porque se esta usando `.map` y este nuevo arreglo  es el que regresa como valor el `.map` externo, y seria la salida que esperas:

```
 [
  [51.505, -0.09],
  [51.51, -0.1],
  [51.51, -100.12],
]
```

Espero te ayude.
Te dejo el link de la documentacion del metodo `.map` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) y `Object.keys` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: El detalle que completamente estaba descomponiendo un poco los datos, era el areglo con el cual iteraba con el for, esto principalmente porque lo recibo de un API externa, pero gracias a ti ya pude modificar todo y todo funciona de maravilla. Muchas gracias.